# Is it LightSwitch bug? Problems with re sizing controls

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

Please download source code for "Beginning Microsoft Visual Studio LightSwitch Development" book
http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Beginning-Microsoft-Visual-Studio-LightSwitch-Development.productCd-1118021959,descCd-DOWNLOAD.html

When you run code from "Chapter 09\Sample 6 - Value Pickers" folder
you will see this badly formatted Project Details tab:
[image: Project Details tab]

As you can see there is big gap between Customer and Code rows, but on the figure 
in the book there is no gap. I've tried to change the height of Customer control
but it won't change the height of the gap.

Please help.

Robert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer
http://p2p.wrox.com/book-beginning-microsoft-visual-studio-lightswitch-development/84982-chapter-9-cant-change-height-customer-cell-control.html